# SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I got this in npm build
im using webpack and babel
I have installed babel loader and ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
still got the same error

```
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (322:6)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: // Transpiles ES6-8 into ES5
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }, 
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
            }